# Can't create a folder in my logical drive - UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied

Tags: c#, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

```
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity ds = new System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity();
                string useraccountForDirectoryCreate = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
                ds.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(useraccountForDirectoryCreate,
                System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                        System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
                        System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                        System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags.None,
                        System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder.Text,ds);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder.Text + "\\timetables",ds);
```

I'm trying to create a folder in my logical drive But I keep getting an exception:
 UnauthorizedAccessException Error : Access Denied I even run as administrator still the same results

Comment: What user account are you using to create the folder?
Do you have permission (or the application running under the account) to create the folder (write permissions)
How is the application running? Are you running it under Windows Service, IIS, or just double clicking on it yourself to execute it?

Comment: its an execuatable and am an administrator i researched file permission and i even tried this(added some new code) gives a different type of error IdentityNotMappedException occured.

Comment: This exception generally means that the program process does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Without showing the code, we cannot help :). Most likely it is the fact that the account you are running under does not have permission to write to the folder. OR the application NEEDS to be executed as an administrator (UAC settings could be applied here on your OS) - so right click > Run as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I re-wrote your code and tested it on my machine.  This code works for me; however, so did your code so you must not have write permission to Program Files.

You should use Path.Combine(...) instead of manually appending your strings.

```
var ttg = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "TimeTableGenerator");
Directory.CreateDirectory(ttg);
```